# Question about the definition of convergence a.e.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty},f(x)$ be a measurable functions on $X$ such that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ a.e.

By definition it means that there is $E\in \mathcal{M}$ s.t. for all $x\in E$ we have $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ and $\mu(X-E)=0$.

So let me ask you the following question: By definition of the set $E$ we have $E=\{x\in X: \lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\}$. Here we mean finite limit or infinite also?

Would be very grateful if anyone will answer and gives some clear examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the limit to be finite. For example if $f_n(x)=n$ for all $n$ and $x$ we can say $f_n \to \infty$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Hmm.. so in your example $E$ is whole $X$, right?

Comment: @ZFR Yes, that is right.

Comment: Dear Dr.Murthy, could you take a look at my topic, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657707/sum-of-measurable-functions-f-gx-to-infty-infty