# Sum of measurable functions $f,g:X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f,g:X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$ be measurable functions. How to prove that $f+g$ is measurable?

I know that if $f,g:X\to (-\infty,+\infty)$ are measurable functions then $f+g$ is measurable and the proof is not difficult. But when we consider functions which takes on infinite values then we have uncertainty of the form $-\infty+\infty$ and $\infty-\infty$.

I would be very grateful if someone will show detailed proof of this fact, please?
I was trying to find it on the internet but I failed.

**Remark:** If we require the measure $\mu$ to be complete and $f,g$ are finite a.e. then we have no troubles. Indeed, the sets $\{x\in X:f(x)=\pm\infty\}$ and $\{x\in X:g(x)=\pm\infty\}$ are measurable with zero measure. Let's check that $f+g$ is measurable. By definition for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$ we have: $$(f+g)^{-1}((c,+\infty]):=\{x\in X: f(x)+g(x)\in (c,+\infty]\}=$$$$=\{x\in X: f(x)+g(x)\in (c,+\infty],\text{both} \ f,g \ \text{are finite}\}\sqcup \{x\in X: f(x)+g(x)\in (c,+\infty],\text{at least one of the is infinite}\}.$$
Let's denote the first and second set by $A$ and $B$, respectively. Then

$$A=\{x\in X: f(x)+g(x)\in (c,+\infty],f<\infty,g<\infty\}=$$$$=\bigcup \limits_{r\in \mathbb{Q}}f^{-1}((r,+\infty])\cap g^{-1}((c-r,+\infty])\cap f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\cap g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\in \mathcal{M}$$
Each set in the union is measurable and since $\mathcal{M}$ is $\sigma$-algebra then $A\in \mathcal{M}$.

The set $B$ we can write in the following form: $$B=\{x\in X:f(x)+g(x)>c, f(x)=\pm\infty\}\cup\{x\in X:f(x)+g(x)>c, g(x)=\pm\infty\}=B_1\cup B_2$$ and since $B_1\subset \{x\in X:f(x)=\pm\infty\}$ and $B_2\subset \{x\in X:g(x)=\pm\infty\}$ and $\mu$ is complete measure then $B_1,B_2\in \mathcal{M}$ and hence $B\in \mathcal{M}$. So this shows that $(f+g)^{-1}((c,+\infty])$ is measurable, i.e. $f+g$ is measurable function.

**Question:** But how to prove this in the case when we omit those conditions, i.e. completeness of $\mu$ and finite a.e.?

Comment: $f+g$ need not be defined. There could be points where $f(x)=-g(x)=\infty$  or $f(x)=-g(x)=-\infty$ You cannot prove measurability of $f+g$  when it is not even well defined.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks a lot for your reply! But let me ask you the following: My book says that if we make convention that $0\times (\pm \infty)=0$ and $\infty-\infty=-\infty-(-\infty)=0$ then we can conclude that $f+g$ is still measurable if $f,g:X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$. Could you explain it to me, please? I will highly appreciate your answer!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, dear Dr. Murthy, could you take at this question, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676746/lebesgue-measure-on-the-semiring-s-a-b-is-sigma-additive